# How to stop setTimeout onClick in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to `Reactjs` and while using `setTimeOut` I got stuck on what is the best way to stop it.Should I use `clearTimeOut` or `stopPropagation()`.

This is my code

```
render: function() {
    return ( < div className = "colorClick"
      style = {
        {
          background: this.state.bgColor
        }
      }
      onClick = {
        this.detectColor
      } > < /div><br/ >
    );
  },
  calcTime: function() {
    var time = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1);
    this.setState({
      total_time: time
    }, () => {
      window.setTimeout(this.calcTime, 250)
    });
  },


  detectColor: function(event) {
    window.clearTimeout(this.state.total_time);
    window.clearTimeout(this.calcTime);
  },


  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.calcTime();
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    this.detectColor();
  }
```

In this code I am using `clearTimeOut` but it is not working.I want that when I click on `div` with `className="colorClick"`, the setimeOut should clear and reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some bad practices in your code. I'll comment in the code the changes. Also, I'm guessing you are using `React.createClass`, which is deprecated.

Use the class syntax instead. and like Horia said, you need to store the timeout in a variable, so the entire code would look something like this:

```
import React from 'react'
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  // notice no ":" and no "function"
  render () {
    return (

      <div {/* no space between "<" and the div */}
        className="colorClick" {/* no space around "=" */}
        style={ { background: this.state.bgColor } } {/* no space around "=" */}
        onClick={ this.clearTimeout } {/* no space around "=" */}
      /> {/* div is self closing, use this when there's no childs */}
    );
  } // no ","

  calcTime () {
    // use const if variable is not reassigned
    const time = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1);
    this.setState({
      total_time: time
    }, () => {
      // assign timeout to component property
      this.timeout = window.setTimeout(this.calcTime, 250)
    });
  }

  // no "event" passed as an argument since its:
  // 1. unnecessary
  // 2. doesn't exit when called in componentWillUnmount
  // method name changed to clearTimeout since it's more accurately describe what it does
  // notice fat arrow syntax to bind clearTimeout context to the class
  clearTimeout = () => {
    // use clearTimeout on the stored timeout in the class property "timeout"
    window.clearTimeout(this.timeout);
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.calcTime();
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    this.clearTimeout();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're using `clearTimeout` incorrectly. You need to store the result of `window.setTimeout` in a variable, and then call `window.clearTimeout` with that variable as argument. Here's an example fro [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp) which shows this.

Comment: I am already doing that way its suggested in w3school.The setTimeOut is working on this.state.total_time and I am doing clearTimeOut on that but still its not working

Comment: You are using the function calcTime as the parameter to clearTimeout. That's not how it works - it needs to get the id returned by setTimeout. See the docs from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout) as well, the "source of truth", as it were.